# The Poco.Crypto library is not linked to libssl.so when building Poco. Why?

Tags: c++, linker, poco, poco-libraries

I'm using Poco libraries on Ubuntu 16.04.6 (kernel 4.19.37) with gcc/g++ v7.4.0.
I have an issue with building Poco 1.9.* package: the Crypto library is not linked to libssl.so after build.

What I do:
First, I configure build system running

```
./configure --no-samples --no-tests --omit=Data,MongoDB --cflags=--std=c++11
```

Then, I call make:

```
make
```

The build script returns NO errors, so I run

```
sudo make install
```

After that I check dependencies of libPocoCrypro.so:

```
ldd /usr/local/lib/libPocoCrypto.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd38af9000)
    libPocoFoundation.so.60 => /usr/local/lib/libPocoFoundation.so.60 (0x00007f8d1dd70000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f8d1db53000)
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f8d1d70e000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f8d1d32b000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f8d1d113000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f8d1cd49000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f8d1cb45000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f8d1c93d000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f8d1c634000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f8d1e3a2000)
```

And there is no entry for libssl.so, only libcrypto.so.
As there is no linkage to libssl.so, all projects that depend on Poco fail to build with error:

```
//usr/local/lib/libPocoCrypto.so: undefined reference to `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_reset'
//usr/local/lib/libPocoCrypto.so: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_init_crypto'
//usr/local/lib/libPocoCrypto.so: undefined reference to `EVP_MD_CTX_new'
//usr/local/lib/libPocoCrypto.so: undefined reference to `EVP_MD_CTX_free'
//usr/local/lib/libPocoCrypto.so: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_init_ssl'
//usr/local/lib/libPocoCrypto.so: undefined reference to `X509_getm_notBefore'
//usr/local/lib/libPocoCrypto.so: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_num'
//usr/local/lib/libPocoCrypto.so: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_pop_free'
//usr/local/lib/libPocoCrypto.so: undefined reference to `RSA_get0_key'
//usr/local/lib/libPocoCrypto.so: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_value'
//usr/local/lib/libPocoCrypto.so: undefined reference to `X509_up_ref'
//usr/local/lib/libPocoCrypto.so: undefined reference to `X509_getm_notAfter'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

There is unambiguous instruction to link to libssl.so in the "Crypto/Makefile":

```
#
# Makefile
#
# Makefile for Poco Crypto
#

include $(POCO_BASE)/build/rules/global

SYSLIBS += -lssl -lcrypto
...
```

There is more strange facts:
1. NetSSl library of the same Poco package links to libssl.so as expected
2. The same Poco package has been linking normally about 3 month ago.
3. I have 7 similar Ubuntu PCs and [exactly] the same Poco package links normally on 5 of them. The only difference between these PCs - is Ubuntu and kernel versions. On Ubuntu 16.04 + 4.19.37 linkage fails, but on Ubuntu 18.04 + 4.15 kernel gets linked normally.

OpenSSl installed:

```
openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017

ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu | grep libssl
libssl3.so
libssl.a
libssl.so
libssl.so.1.1

apt-cache policy libssl-dev
libssl-dev:
  Installed: 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.15
  Candidate: 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.15
  Version table:
 *** 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.15 500
        500 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.0.2g-1ubuntu4 500
        500 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

So I do not understand what causes that issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Is `libssl-dev` installed in your Ubuntu?

Comment: yes, located in '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu'. updated the post.